# Compiling a fortran program on linux and moving the executable to another linux machine

Tags: linux, fortran, portability

I have a code that I have written in Fortran during my PhD, and now I am collaborating with some researcher that uses Linux, and they need my model, that is basically a single executable file. In the future I will probably make it open source, but up to know they just want the executable, also because they are not programmers and they have never compiled a program in their life. So the question is: is it possible to compile it on my linux machine and then send it to them in order to use it in another linux machine?Or does the linux version and distribution matter? 
thank you very much
A.

Comment: It very much matters which flavor of Linux and architecture.  An executable compiled for i386 is challenging to run on an ARM or 68000, though even that can be done using a virtual machine on the other guy's target.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use many libraries you can do that. One option is statically linking the executable (`-static` or similar compiler option). You need to have the static versions of all needed libraries for that. The have `.a` suffix. They are often not installed by default in Linux distributions and often they are not supplied in the repositories at all.

In my distrbution (OpenSuSE) they are in packages like `glibc-devel-static`, `lapack-devel-static` and similar.

The other option would be to compile the executable on a compatible distribution the users will have (GLIBC version is important) and supply all `.so` dynamically linked libraries they will need with your executable.

All of this assumes you use the same platform, like `i586` or `amd64` or `arm` like wallyk comments. I mostly assumed you are on a PC. You can force most compilers to produce a 32-bit or 64-bit executable by `-m32` or `-m64` option. You need the right version of the development libraries for that.

Comment: Thanks. So my model has only f90 subroutines with no external libraries. My architecture is the same as the one of the other person i.e. it is a x86_64. I dont know if the Linux distribution matters but I have Centos 6.3 and the other person Fedora (we had trouble to check the version but it should be 14). Could you please modify your answer for the case of no external libraries and same architecture? What do u mean with " right version of development libraries"? Thanks

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer, it I mostly assumed same architecture. By " right version of development libraries" I meant 3-bit or 64-bit depending what version of your program do you compile. Just try to compile with the `-static` option and see if it works on the other machine.